# Control margins for each column separately in \twocolumn mode

Tags: two-column, geometry

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{forloop}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\geometry{a3paper, landscape, top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

\newcounter{Loop}
\newcounter{LoopTotal}
\setcounter{LoopTotal}{16}

\forloop{Loop}{1}{\value{Loop}<\value{LoopTotal}}{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas est metus, volutpat sit amet nulla vitae, mattis ornare dolor. Proin fermentum urna in felis iaculis aliquet. Mauris dolor neque, pulvinar rutrum quam a, dictum auctor quam. Integer massa orci, vestibulum at ipsum sed, bibendum condimentum orci. Donec sagittis, lectus lacinia commodo egestas, urna nisl pellentesque elit, imperdiet aliquet est ex eu enim. Suspendisse venenatis elit at turpis lacinia faucibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi tincidunt consequat turpis, quis venenatis nisi congue sit amet. Integer egestas vel tortor sit amet venenatis. Phasellus ac dignissim neque. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed massa neque, blandit eget lobortis et, dignissim nec ipsum.\par
}

\end{document}
```

I want to shrink bottom margin of second (only second) column on every page (I have complex footers in my document). In single column document I would do this with `\newgeometry{...,bottom=5cm,...}`.

Maybe with `etoolbox` package I can append `\enlargethispage{-3cm}` to something, that going on at the end of every first column?

EDIT:
Package `flowfram` didn't work for me since it collides with other packages I use in my document.

Comment: Any restrictions as to your submission? I'd suggest using [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) for this...

Comment: This is interesting suggestion! I basically can emulate `\twocolumn` mode with it. Do you know if it would work with `longtable`? I mean to start table in one flowframe and continue it in another.

Comment: I don't know (never tried it), but this is not mentioned in your question. You should make a complete example of what you're trying to achieve, including the elements you *may* consider down the road. Otherwise possible solutions may fall short of your objective.

Comment: I want to correct bottom margin for the second column in `\twocolumn` mode. That's it. Your suggestion is valid, but I wonder if it's possible by changing some tex inner value or hooking to something that automatically issued at the end of first column.

Comment: ...other packages? Like [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable)? What other packages? Obviously if your restrictions are too strong, there might not be a viable answer. That's okay as well, perhaps not for you though...

Comment: No it seems, it was something else, I don't really know. Regarding `longtable`, it's just old problem I have: make `longtable` or `tabu` to span in multiple columns on single page. It isn't related to this question, sorry for confusion :(

Comment: Don't use `tabu` unless you know what the possible consequences are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found simple solution using `\AtBeginShipout` hook.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\geometry{a3paper, landscape, top=2cm,bottom=5cm,left=3cm,right=2cm}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

\AtBeginShipout{
\enlargethispage{3cm}
}

\newcounter{Loop}
\newcounter{LoopTotal}
\setcounter{LoopTotal}{16}

\enlargethispage{3cm}
\forloop{Loop}{1}{\value{Loop}<\value{LoopTotal}}{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas est metus, volutpat sit amet nulla vitae, mattis ornare dolor. Proin fermentum urna in felis iaculis aliquet. Mauris dolor neque, pulvinar rutrum quam a, dictum auctor quam. Integer massa orci, vestibulum at ipsum sed, bibendum condimentum orci. Donec sagittis, lectus lacinia commodo egestas, urna nisl pellentesque elit, imperdiet aliquet est ex eu enim. Suspendisse venenatis elit at turpis lacinia faucibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi tincidunt consequat turpis, quis venenatis nisi congue sit amet. Integer egestas vel tortor sit amet venenatis. Phasellus ac dignissim neque. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed massa neque, blandit eget lobortis et, dignissim nec ipsum.\par
}

\end{document}
```

Although I haven't figured out a way to control margin for second column explicitly, this helped me to change it for every first column and then offset it with geometry package (`bottom=5cm`) for whole page so it has exactly same effect.